# Parsing float is rounding the value incorrectly in Java

Tags: java

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float amt = Float.valueOf("21111111.00");
        System.out.printf("%f\n", amt);

    }
}
```

Output is:
21111112.000000

Why is the float value being incremented by 1 automatically?

Comment: Isn't it just because `float`s don't have enough mantissa?

Comment: That is the nearest representative value. Try `double` instead.

Comment: Floating-point types are inherently imprecise, and the precision of the type`float` is only about 6 or 7 decimal digits.

Comment: Actually , it is giving a number greater than what i am passing, so i am within the range and error is not been thrown. Please suggest an better option.

Comment: Use `double`, this gives you about 15 decimal digits precision.

Comment: Float has limited precision (this is not the same as the range!) "21111111.00" cannot be represented as float - the nearest possible float values are "21111110" and "21111112"

Comment: Even when i pass the 21111111, it doesn't return the equivalent number.What is the crux of using float in java and why it is returning a different number instead of an error.

Comment: There is no error. This number simply has too many significant digits to be exactly represented in a `float`. The result is as close to the true value as it can get.

Comment: float has only 24 bits of mantissa, which corresponds to ~7 digits of precision. 21111111 has 8 digits